# Did Daniel (briefly) ascend at the end of "Threads"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Daniel spends the majority of the season 8 episode "Threads" in a sort of limbo while Oma waits for him to choose ascension over (apparently) being killed by the replicators in a previous episode.

At the end of the episode, he emerges naked from a room in the SGC. So, did he:

1. **Ascend and immediately re-banish himself to "life"?**
   i. If so, who helped him ascend since Oma was locked in battle with Anubis?
   ii. How come he could choose his destination on this occasion, while when returning from a higher plane in season 7 he's put in the middle of nowhere?
   iii. Why would he re-banish himself so soon?;
   *or*
2. **Get returned to life by the other Ancients sitting around eating waffles** (although they'd ignored him completely up to that point)?
   i. Why would they do this vs. just let him die?

So I guess I am asking what happened, and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The implication is that he *self-ascended*, then chose to assume human form once more.**

Note that at the point that he enters the "cosmic diner", he's already in a position to choose to either ascend or die on his *own* merits. Oma makes it abundantly clear that Daniel possesses sufficient knowledge about the process of ascension (courtesy of her teachings at [Kheb](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Kheb)) and that her work is [basically done](https://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Stargate-SG1-Threads.html):

> **OMA:** *I can’t get into it. What’s stopping you from ascending?*
>
> **DANIEL:** *I don’t know.*
>
> **OMA:** *Must be something holding you back - making you doubt yourself.*
>   **DANIEL:** *Maybe it’s not me I’m doubting.*
>
> **OMA:** *Look, **whether you choose to accept living on a higher plane of existence has nothing to do with me** or anything that I can
>   or can’t tell you. **It’s all up to you.***

Comment: Oma sure did have a shorter fuse in that episode than the prior ones. She's had it with Daniels indecisive bs

Answer (score 1):

Oma had ascended Anubis and was punished for it. She never helped ascend Daniel, just hinted at it. It was the border of help and guide, a very fine line. The first time Daniel met Oma, on that planet, from when she helped teach the Hacisis, to Daniel dying the first time, was straddling the line of *helping*, all she did was riddle Daniel to his own potential. It was all his work and effort that allowed him to move on. Even after descending, Daniel was still as dense as always. His second ascension was just as much all his work as his first. And as we have seen through the other ancient Orlin, ascending is done completely on their own will/recognisense.

The ancients in the diner, as metaphors for the real ancients, have a strict non interference policy that would make Star Fleet jealous. They punished Oma for interfering before, and would never lend a hand in helping Daniel. In fact, his first stint as an Ascended being was hampered by their rules which they enforce with prejudice. They would never help him ascend or descend, no matter how likeable a person Daniel is.

Comment: It's pretty clear from what Oma says that she was instrumental in helping him to ascend both times "*he killed you to stop you. That's where I stepped in. How's that?*"